# Is there anyway I can get rid of this "extra cheek" under my bum?

Tags: weight-loss, body-fat, burn-fat

I have had this "extra cheek" since I can remember, and I've always been insecure about it. I try to do squats to get rid of it but I always give up after a week :/ 
please help me!
(https://i.stack.imgur.com/bqIJn.jpg)

Answer (score -1):

This may sound counter-intuitive, but jumping exercises will help. They can strengthen the core and activate your thighs, so you'll be able to progress faster with a more demanding cardio routine.

Squats, repetitive ones I presume, are boring as hell. That's why a combination of jumping moves with getting into the half-squat position might help. You'll be activating the muscles necessary, and also burning a bit of calories at the same time.

As for leg specific exercises, and strength training for achieving a better "burn" try squats again, but add a gamification element. Mike Tyson, allegedly, invented a sequence where you are [performing squats](https://www.lifestyleupdated.com/2018/05/21/the-mike-tysons-squat-routine-fun-intense-squat-workout/) ad infinitum, and it is a rather fun burnout session to go over.

Comment: Thank you very much I will definitely try this out and I'll continue doing this regularly :) how long do you think it'll take to get results?